# how to add new .webm mime types

Tags: uploads, server, videos

i tried google but no success yet.

I am trying to upload .webm and .ogg video types in wordpress ( for html5 video ofcourse)
I am getting error like

```
Baki fula.webm” has failed to upload due to an error
Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.
```

tried plugins like

1. PJW Mime Config
2. AP Extended Mime Types

but doesnot seem to work either. 
I am working locally with easyphp in windows 7 in wordpress 3.4.1.

Can anyone plase help me in solving this issue. Any help is appreciated

Comment: I recomend you look up server mime types and you can add them to your .htaccess file  ... but this is more a question for another stackexchange forum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WebM file format isn't known to WordPress by default, you have to add it.

```
add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'custom_mimes' );
function custom_mimes( $mimes ){
    $mimes['webm'] = 'video/webm';
    return $mimes;
}
```

The .ogg file format is known to WordPress as audio/ogg, if you're wanting to do video with it, the correct extension is .ogv.